# AngularJS - Wait for View HTML to Load Before Executing Variable Assignment?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I have a page in AngularJS that looks like

```
<body ng-controller="mainController">
    <my-view></my-view>
</body>
```

Inside the `my-view` file, I have an input element:

```
<div>
    <input id="my-input" type="file"> 
</div>
```

In my `mainController`, I assign the file input element to a `$scope` variable.  In about 50% of page loads, the `$scope` variable is assigned a null value.  I assume this is because the  element hasn't actually been loaded onto the DOM when my controller assigns the variable.

I tried using

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
    $scope.fileChooser = document.getElementById('my-input');
});
```

but this doesn't seem to solve the problem since the request for the `my-view` HTML file is asynchronous and is made after the initial page load.  I found a temporary solution by wrapping the variable assignment inside of a `setTimeout()`, but I'd like to avoid this.

Is there a built-in way in Angular to wait for all views to load before performing code execution?

Comment: Maybe it is nicer to use angular.element insted of document.getElementById?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing the variable assignment inside of my directive instead of my controller.

```
myApp.directive('myView', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: '=',
        templateUrl: '/path/to/html.html',
        link: function(){
            // Assign input element to scope variable
            scope.fileChooser = document.getElementById('my-input');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Experiment with the directive `postLink` feature.

But you could also try using `ng-model=""` on your input field, and targeting the field that way instead of by element. You can also use `$watch(...)` to set a watcher that fires when the value of this ng-model changes.